# CSS: Stop div and img from overlapping

Tags: css, image, html, overlapping, figure

I have a figure with an img inside it floating to the right and a div.
My html is

```
<div>
<figure id="fig">
<img src="img.jpg"></img>
<figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
<div id="inner">
Blah Blah Blah
</div>
</div>
```

My div css is

```
#inner{
text-align: center;
width: 70%;
margin: auto;
padding: 1% 5%;
}
```

and my figure css is

```
#fig{
width:162px;
height:277px;
margin:auto 7px auto 7px;
float:right;
}
```

and my img css is

```
img{
width:162px;
height:277px;
}
```

My div is under the figure. The problem is that the div's width is 70% and if the figure comes in front of it, it doesnt know. I want the div to be 70% of the space - the figure.

Comment: can you post some more complete code, your full css for that section and your html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the width from your `#inner` div and set a margin on the right of it that is the full width ( margin + padding + width + etc. ) of your `figure`.  The `figure` will float into the right margin of `#inner`.  Since DIVs are block level elements they take up 100% width by default.

http://jsfiddle.net/kacH7/

*CSS*

```css
#fig {
     width: 162px;
     height: 277px;
     float: right;
     margin: auto 7px;
}
#inner {
     text-align: center;
     padding: 1% 5%;
     margin-right: 176px;
     background-color: red; /* demonstration only */
}
img {
     width: 162px;
     height: 277px;
}
```